# How to reset sap ui5 input fields by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

i have created one submission form by using java script i need to reset the input data by using on reset button.
Help me out of this.

```
reset: function() {
    var oInput1 = sap.ui.getCore().byId("firstname");
    oInput1.setValue("");*/
    this.getViewById("firstname").setValue("");*/
}

    input1.getId("firstname").setValue("");

onExit: function() {
    input1.setValue("");
}
```

the code is not resetting the form data

Answer (score 0):

First of all your provided code-sample is incorrect, please correct it.

Second, `onExit` is executed when your view is destroyed, setting the input value to empty is rather useless there.

If you want to reset data of your input-field when clicking a button you'll need to have the following elements:

1) an [Input](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input)- & [Button](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Button)-control (with press-event) in your XML-view.

2) an id assigned to your Input-control to be able to refer to the control when pressing the reset-button.

3) The press-event from the  button worked out in your controller.

**XML**

```
<Input id="firstname" value=""/>
<Button text="Reset" press="reset"/>
```

**Controller**

```
reset: function() {
    var oInput1 = this.getView().byId("firstname");
    oInput1.setValue("");
}
```